# Database update issue using node-orm2 for mysql backend

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-orm2

Problem:
 I am working on an Android app which interacts with nodejs REST server using node orm for mysql backend. On my server, I have a functionality of authenticating users based on email verification. Once verification is successful, node orm fetches the user object, changes the verified column value and saves it back. 
But, the change is not reflecting in the db after execution. Only if we run the same code another time, it is reflecting in the database

Code

```
    exports.activateEmail = function(email, callback) {
    log.info('In verifyEmailDao.js, activateEmail module');
    var db = connectionObj.getConnection();
    var Candidate = db.models.jobseeker_id;

  Candidate.find({email : email}, function(err,candidate){
    if(err){
      log.info('cannot find account with email to activate', email);
      callback(false, null);
    }
    else {
      candidate[0].verified = true;
        log.info('candidate email now activated.! status is', candidate[0].verified);
      candidate[0].save(function(error){
        log.info('Email verified any errors?', error);
        callback(true, candidate[0].id);
      });
       }
   });
}
```

Edit 1:

jobseeker_id.js (node-orm model)

```
var orm = require('orm');
module.exports = function(db){
  console.log('coming inside candidateId.js');
  var JobSeekerId = db.define('jobseeker_id', {
    id : {type:'serial' , key:true},
    first_name : String,
    last_name : String,
    email : String,
    password : String,
    verified : Boolean
  },{
    validations : {
      email : orm.enforce.unique("Already registered")
    }
  });
}
```

Server log:

```
{"name":"test-app" "msg":"In verifyEmailDao.js, activateEmail module"}
{"name":"test-app","msg":"candidate email now activated.! status is true"}
{"name":"test-app","msg":"Email verified any errors? null"}
{"name":"test-app","msg":"Email sucessfully activated. Now deleting the entry from verify email link table for candidate id 30}
{"name":"test-app","msg":"In verifyEmailDao.js, deleteRandomLink module"}
{"name":"test-app","msg":"error is---> null"}
{"name":"test-app","msg":"Entry deleted from verify email table as email is activated"}
```

There will no be no changes in the log when I execute the code for second time, but the change in the db will be reflected!

Comment: Maybe share the db.models.jobseeker_id as well as the output of the logs.

Comment: yeah now added the model file and server log @akaphenom

Comment: Odd. You will probably have to debug their code, and see what it going on.  From what I remember I didnt love their code (its been a while), but I would probably start evaluating as close to the driver as possible and work back up the stack.  There is either the Model and/or Instance objects that abstract persistence layer - the problem / answer is most likley in there - but like I said - see if the "inserts" are happening and walk back up the stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days of hell I finally fixed the issue by adding a statement `db.settings.set('instance.cache', false)` to the db config file. Though I did'nt clearly understand how db update issue was resolved by setting the cache to false, this did the trick!